# SQL timeout CommandTimeout routinely timing out

Tags: vba, excel, sql-server-2008, connection

I am having a problem with my a connection from Excel to SQL server 2008.  I run the file daily and routinely, the first time i run it i get a bypass timeout error.

To pre-empt the "Make the conn.CommandTimeout longer" argument, I would suggest the problem is not directly related to the length of the window as:

> The query takes only a couple of seconds in SQL server
>
> The second time i run the script it works fine, and 12 queries are run in under the total timeout time.

What is the best way to proceed with this?  My initial thoughts are to use an error handler to retry without user input on a timeout error, but this will increase the timeout window to 3 mins which is undesirable.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub ConnectServer(FileName As String, rngToPrint As Range, strSqlQuery As String)
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim iCols As Long

    If Not (rs Is Nothing) Then
        If (rs.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If


    sConnString = "poop"

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    conn.CommandTimeout = 90

    conn.Open sConnString

    Set rs = conn.Execute(strSqlQuery)


    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Sheets(rngToPrint.Worksheet.Name).Cells(rngToPrint.Row - 1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next

    If Not rs.EOF Then

        rngToPrint.CopyFromRecordset rs
        rs.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If

    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This may apply to your situation: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: @Alex K. That's a fair comment, and I will read it over lunch, I'm not sure it will address the point that it will address the second point that it runs fine and quickly the second time round, but i will give it a read, thanks